# Rails Paperclip Save Images from URL into Database

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, paperclip

I have a Rails app with underlying MySQL database containing many products. 
Each product has a picture, which is currently stored in the database as URL.

How can I save these with paperclip on S3. How do I store the filename in my MySQL database? And how do I trigger the refresh, once I updated my database with hundreds of new products?

Thanks a lot for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to download the image from the url and let paperclip do the reprocessing for you. You can find code to download the image on paperclip's wiki https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/wiki/Attachment-downloaded-from-a-URL

For the sake of the example, let's say you have Users with avatars, rather than products with images and the existing field is `old_avatar_url`. Setup User to store an avatar, as instructed by **paperclip**.

```
User.find_each do |user|
  user.avatar_remote_url = user.old_avatar_url
  user.save
end
```

After than you can safely remove the `old_avatar_url` column.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Leito! Is there any way to avoid the script from ending once there is an error? I regularly get the error "bad URI(is not URI?): " from some urls. Those should be just ignored.

Comment: I got it solved myself like this.. Thanks again!                                                 def get_image_from_link
    unless url.blank?
    encoded_url  = URI.encode(url).to_s
    self.image  = URI.parse(encoded_url)
    end
  end

Comment: Good to know, so the error you were getting was because you had blank url's? Please mark this answer or create your own so others have a clear picture of how the problem was solved without reading all the comments.

Comment: Changed. Thanks for all your input.